# python 2.7.5: run a whole function in background

Tags: background-process

I am a beginner with python. I want to run a whole function in the background (because it can take a while or even fail).
Here is the function:

```
def backup(str):
    command = barman_bin + " backup " + str
    log_maif.info("Lancement d'un backup full:")
    log_maif.info(command)
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode == 0:
        for line in output[0].decode(encoding='utf-8').split('\n'):
            log_maif.info(line)
    else:
        for line in output[0].decode(encoding='utf-8').split('\n'):
            log_maif.error(line)
    log_maif.info("Fin du backup full")
    return output
```

I want to run this function in the background into a loop :

```
for host in list_hosts_sans_doublon:
    backup(host) # <-- how to run the whole function in background ?
```

In ksh, I would have written something like `backup $host &`  with backup a function that takes $host as an argument.

Comment: Hi Eric. Not an expert but I believe what you are looking for is an async way to run a function. You might want to look into the documentation and try to find how to achieve async behavior.

Comment: Thank you xploraj. I had a try with async but I encountered errors as "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" that I failed to fix, that's why I am asking ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is to run the function in a different thread from what I understand. For this you need to use python thread module.
This is how you start a thread:

```
import threading
def backup(mystring):
    print(mystring)

host="hello"
x = threading.Thread(target=backup, [host])
x.start()
Do what ever you want after this and the thread will run separately.
```

Comment: Thank you Fadi Abu Raid. I confirm, that's what I am looking for. I just had to write x = threading.Thread(target=backup, args=(host,)) and then it worked.